# wildfly performance , high usage eden space without use it

Tags: java, heap-memory, wildfly, eden

We have a `Wildfly` containger with 8Gb. It configured to use G1 as garbage collector.

We had problems of usage with eden space, in 1 hour `Wildfly` uses all eden space without any wars.
This only happens with wildfly, we tried the same memory configuration in `Tomcat` and usage is normal.
Also we remove scanner.
When we activated `Dynatrace` the performance got even worst.

> -server -Xms8024m -Xmx8024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC
> -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=5

Same happens without `G1GC` , only diference is that PS Eden Space reserve by default less heap.

We don't understand this behavior and how much it can affect performance.  gc is done when eden is full and seems to don't produce almost suspension but still we don't like it.

Does anyone know if this is normal in Wildfly / Jboss?

Thanks in advance.

We try disable Dynatrace,remove wars, heap-dumps that didn't show nothing special...we try to use the latest Wildfly with JDK11.
The only difference was that without Dynatrace eden memory grows slower.